# How to remove an excel file with same name as pdf counterpart?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Imagine you want to remove a file in a directory which is Excel, but only if it is the same name as a PDF in the same directory.

Have tried the following:

```
import os

    #if both excel and pdf, remove excel
    directory = r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\git\yourubl\attachments\75090058\Status\Verwerking"
    pdffile = os.path.join(directory, '.pdf')
    excelfile = os.path.join(directory, '.xlsx')
    
    if pdffile == excelfile:
        os.remove(excelfile)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pathlib` to accomplish that straightforward:

```
import pathlib

directory = pathlib.Path(r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\git\yourubl\attachments\75090058\Status\Verwerking")

for f in directory.glob('*.xlsx'):
    if f.with_suffix('.pdf').exists():
        f.unlink()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your if with the following if condition and try,

```
if os.path.exists(pdffile) and os.path.exists(excelfile):
    os.remove(excelfile)
```

Your code doesn't mention anything about file names. You can find all pdf filenames in a directory using `glob` [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Tried it and nothing happens so I think there may be an error here:
pdffile = os.path.join(directory, '.pdf')
excelfile = os.path.join(directory, '.xlsx')

Comment: Whats the error message? and is the directory variable a filename or a folder name?

Answer (score 0):

For all files in your directory you may want to use sets:

```
pdf = set([f[:-4] for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mypath, f)) and f.endswith('.pdf')])
xl = set([f[:-5] for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mypath, f)) and f.endswith('.xlsx')])

to_del = [str(i)+'.xlsx' for i in list(a&b)]
for f in to_del:
  os.remove(os.path.join(mypath, f))
```